# Is there a way to keep a background color displaying for an amount of time that doesnt pause the game? PYTHON

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to keep the screen green for a time and register KEYDOWNS but I cant while the pygame.time.wait function is running

```
       self.screen.fill(self.red)
        pygame.time.wait(self.wait)
        rect = self.text.get_rect()
        rect = rect.move(500,500)
        self.screen.blit(self.text, rect)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    

            print "Ouch"
            self.lives -= 1
            print self.lives
            self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            self.text = sysfont.render("Lives: %d" % self.lives, True, (255, 255, 255))
            self.screen.blit(self.text, (25, 25))                       
            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make something like this: (5 seconds = 5000 milliseconds)

```
time_to_change_color = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 5000 # 5 seconds

# main loop
while TRUE:

    # place for events

    if pygame.time.get_ticks() < time_to_change_color:
        self.screen.fill(self.GREEN)
    else:
        self.screen.fill(self.BLACK)

    # place for blits

    pygame.display.flip()
```

or like this:

```
time_to_change_color = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 5000 # 5 seconds
current_background_color = self.GREEN

# main loop
while TRUE:

    # place for events

    if pygame.time.get_ticks() > time_to_change_color:
        current_background_color = self.BLACK

    self.screen.fill(current_background_color)

    # place for blits

    pygame.display.flip()
```